# Memory management / caching for costly objects in C#

Tags: c#, caching, memory-management, garbage-collection, weak-references

Assume that I have the following object

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ReadOnlyDictionary<T, V> Dict
    {
        get
        {
            return createDictionary();
        }
    }
}
```

Assume that `ReadOnlyDictionary` is a read-only wrapper around `Dictionary<T, V>`.

The `createDictionary` method takes significant time to complete and returned dictionary is relatively large.

Obviously, I want to implement some sort of caching so I could reuse result of `createDictionary` but also I do not want to abuse garbage collector and use to much memory.

I thought of using `WeakReference` for the dictionary but not sure if this is best approach.

What would you recommend? How to properly handle result of a costly method that might be called multiple times?

UPDATE:

I am interested in an advice for a C# 2.0 library (single DLL, non-visual). The library might be used in a desktop of a web application.

UPDATE 2:

The question is relevant for read-only objects as well. I changed value of the property from `Dictionary` to `ReadOnlyDictionary`.

UPDATE 3:

The `T` is relatively simple type (string, for example). The `V` is a custom class. You might assume that an instance of `V` is costly to create. The dictionary might contain from 0 to couple of thousands elements.

The code assumed to be accessed from a single thread or from multiple threads with an external synchronization mechanism.

I am fine if the dictionary is GC-ed when no one uses it. I am trying to find a balance between time (I want to somehow cache the result of `createDictionary`) and memory expenses (I do not want to keep memory occupied longer than necessary).

Comment: What about using external systems? memcached (with expiration) maybe?

Comment: Is this for a web or desktop app?

Comment: @dbaseman please see my update to the question.

Comment: What's wrong with WeakReference? It seems like a very good approach.

Comment: @eyossi honestly, I never tried memcached. and I would like to not introduce any external dependencies to the code.

Comment: You are allowing the client code to modify the dictionary.  Hard to provide caching in such a case.  Think this through, not enough info in the question to help us help you.

Comment: @Bobrovsky So i guess WeakReference is the approach... but maybe not to the whole dictionary, try applying it to it's values

Comment: @HansPassant I changed/updated the question to use read-only value for the property. Is there something else that might help you to help me?

Comment: If the data in the dictionary changes rarely or never, you can implement the property as a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). The dictionary will stay in the memory and eat some space, but you only need to create it once.

Comment: @zmbq the "Guidelines" on MSDN state:  *Avoid using weak references as an automatic solution to memory management problems. Instead, develop an effective caching policy for handling your application's objects.*

Comment: It's not an automatic solution, it's a solution chosen after consideration. It doesn't say "Avoid using weak references at all costs"...

Comment: @Filip I don't see how I can use a singleton here. There might be more than one instance of the `MyClass` and these instance do not share the same data.

Comment: Wrong phrasing on my side. Not a Singleton, but lazy loading in the getter (and storing the result in a backing private field)

Comment: What does the dictionary creation code do?  Could you replace this property with a method that takes a T and returns a V and which caches individual requests but NOT the whole dictionary?

Comment: @IanMercer dictionary creation code traverse some internal [complex] structures, creates/deserialize these structures if needed etc. Unfortunately, I can't replace the property with a method (because of backward-compatibility requirement)

Comment: Well, how large is large?  How many dictionaries do you intend to create?  What's the harm of keeping the entire dictionary in memory?  Will it take up storage in the LOH?

Comment: @ChrisO I have different classes that are designed in a *similar* way. And I experience some problems (OutOfMemoryException on 32bit PCs, huge amounts of data consumed on 64bit PCs).

Comment: @Bobrovsky How about putting the dictionaries into a database instead?

Comment: @ChrisO database might be good for memory, but my library doesn't always need _all dictionaries_ to be constructed at the same time and usually there is no need to keep any data between runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four major mechanisms available for you (Lazy comes in 4.0, so it is no option)

1. lazy initialization
2. virtual proxy
3. ghost
4. value holder

each has it own advantages.

i suggest a value holder, which populates the dictionary on the first call of the GetValue 
method of the holder. then you can use that value as long as you want to AND it is only 
done once AND it is only done when in need.

for more information, see [martin fowlers page](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html)

Answer (score 3):

WeakReference is not a good solution for a cache since you object won´t survive the next GC if nobody else is referencing your dictionary. You can make a simple cache by storing the created value in a member variable and reuse it if it is not null.

This is not thread safe and you would end up in some situations creating the dictionary several times if you have heavy concurent access to it. You can use the double checked lock pattern to guard against this with minimal perf impact.

To help you further you would need to specify if concurrent access is an issue for you and how much memory your dictionary does consume and how it is created. If e.g. the dictionary is the result of an expensive query it might help to simply serialize the dictionary to disc and reuse it until you need to recreate it (this depends on your specific needs).

Caching is another word for memory leak if you have no clear policy when your object should be removed from the cache. Since you are trying WeakReference I assume you do not know when exactly a good time would be to clear the cache.

Another option is to compress the dictionary into a less memory hungry structure. How many keys does your dictionary has and what are the values?

Comment: You say V is costly to create. Is the dictionary always fully accessed? If not you could just keep a most recently used list of Vs in your cache the calculate the rest. Or even better you can create a dictionary of K,Lazy<V> where the value is created for the dictionary only when it is accessed.

Comment: The dictionary might be accessed in an arbitrary way (I do not have data about how often it's accessed). Your idea about Lazy<V> is interested, thank you. Not sure how it will affect GC, though.

Comment: It is hard to optimize if you do not have measured data. If you want the speed cache it in a member variable. If you want to save memory you should not recreate the dictionary again on every access since you have then 2 or more copies in memory at one time which might occupy at worst n-times the memory you wanted to save in the first place. Unconditional caching at this level will spare memory and run time costs. If you want to optimize further you need data about the usage pattern to see if only a small set of keys if ever accessed or if some other parts might be cached to disc....

Comment: I am afraid I won't be able to come up with data about how the dictionary is used. One user of the library might use all values from the dictionary. Another user might never use the property at all.

Comment: Is there any similarity between your Vs? If yes you could try to combine V instances by providing a V-Factory which keeps all Vs but does throw awy the identical ones (String.Intern would be an example of this approach). This does also work for the Ks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to cache the entire dictionary?

From what you say, it might be better to keep a Most-Recently-Used list of key-value pairs.

If the key is found in the list, just return the value.

If it is not, create the one value (which is supposedly faster than creating all of them, and using less memory too) and store it in the list, thereby removing the key-value pair that hasn't been used the longest.

Here's a very simple MRU list implementation, it might serve as inspiration:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

internal sealed class MostRecentlyUsedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> items;
    private readonly int maxCount;

    public MostRecentlyUsedList(int maxCount, IEnumerable<T> initialData)
        : this(maxCount)
    {
        this.items.AddRange(initialData.Take(maxCount));
    }

    public MostRecentlyUsedList(int maxCount)
    {
        this.maxCount = maxCount;
        this.items = new List<T>(maxCount);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an item to the top of the most recently used list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item to add.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if the list was updated, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
    public bool Add(T item)
    {
        int index = this.items.IndexOf(item);

        if (index != 0)
        {
            // item is not already the first in the list
            if (index > 0)
            {
                // item is in the list, but not in the first position
                this.items.RemoveAt(index);
            }
            else if (this.items.Count >= this.maxCount)
            {
                // item is not in the list, and the list is full already
                this.items.RemoveAt(this.items.Count - 1);
            }

            this.items.Insert(0, item);

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

In your case, T is a key-value pair. Keep maxcount small enough, so that searching stays fast, and to avoid excessive memory usage. Call Add each time you use an item.

Comment: Your MRU list has several problems. First you should cache the dictionary key was well. Otherwise you have a hard time finding the right V for a given key ever again. Second you rely on the default comparer for V which is by default reference equality which is wrong. You cannot assume that V does implement GetHashCode and Equals properly if it is used as value in a dictionary. Third if you do cache many entries List.Contains becomes very slow. A Hashset might be faster at the cost of addtional memory that you need to keep the Vs in an extra HashSet.

Comment: I know it has problems. That's why I said "a very simple MRU list implementation, it might serve as inspiration" and "in your case, T is a key-value pair". My point was to say: maybe you don't need to cache the entire dictionary, only recently used items.

Comment: Yes that is right. To optimize correctly we should have more data if there is an actual problem or if we are trying hard to solve a non issue.

Answer (score 1):

An application should use `WeakReference` as a caching mechanism if the useful lifetime of an object's presence in the cache will be comparable to reference lifetime of the object.  Suppose, for example, that you have a method which will create a `ReadOnlyDictionary` based on deserializing a `String`.  If a common usage pattern would be to read a string, create a dictionary, do some stuff with it, abandon it, and start again with another string, `WeakReference` is probably not ideal.  On the other hand, if your objective is to deserialize many strings (quite a few of which will be equal) into `ReadOnlyDictionary` instances, it may be very useful if repeated attempts to deserialize the same string yield the same instance.  Note that the savings would not just come from the fact that one only had to do the work of building the instance once, but also from the facts that (1) it would not be necessary to keep multiple instances in memory, and (2) if `ReadOnlyDictionary` variables refer to the same instance, they can be known to be equivalent without having to examine the instances themselves.  By contrast, determining whether two distinct `ReadOnlyDictionary` instances were equivalent might require examining all the items in each.  Code which would have to do many such comparisons could benefit from using a `WeakReference` cache so that variables which hold equivalent instances would usually hold the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two mechanisms you can rely on for caching, instead of developing your own. The first, as you yourself suggested, was to use a WeakReference, and to let the garbage collector decide when to free this memory up.

You have a second mechanism - memory paging. If the dictionary is created in one swoop, it'll probably be stored in a more or less continuous part of the heap. Just keep the dictionary alive, and let Windows page it out to the swap file if you don't need it. Depending on your usage (how random is your dictionary access), you may end up with better performance than the WeakReference.

This second approach is problematic if you're close to your address space limits (this happens only in 32-bit processes).

Comment: Sorry but a WeakReference will be cleaned as soon as nobody else references this dictionary which will render your cache useless. Paging does not help since the managed heap is (nearly) never paged out since the GC does touch all GC Heaps quite frequently.

Comment: Are you saying .NET programs never get paged out?

Comment: If you are doing frequent allocations the chances are dim that much of your GC heaps will ever be paged out. Although there are chances that you can achieve it when you have a specific allocation pattern. The GC makes use of GetWriteWatch Api to check if a region of memory has been altered since it was last visited so (in theory) it does not need to touch it again.

Comment: @AloisKraus You said "a WeakReference will be cleaned as soon as nobody else references this dictionary", which is obviously not true. It will be cleaned up as soon as the garbage collector runs on generation zero, unless something holds a strong reference at that point in time, in which case it will be cleaned up as soon as the GC runs on generation one (unless something holds a reference at that moment, in which case ... generation two). Weak references can stay alive for a very long time in some cases. Note: this is not to say that a WeakReference is the best caching technique.

Comment: @Kris: My point was that if you do not ensure that you keep a reference to it your cache will not work. Any application which does some real work you will have hundreds of GCs/minute. The time gap between GCs is therefore very small. You are right that my statement is not 100% technically correct but the issue will remain. I too have tried to use WeakReferences for a cache. I found that the cache was never hit ....

Comment: You're forgetting some code is actually using the dictionary, so a strong reference will be kept when it's in use. It will be cleared out of the cache after some period of in-use, which is the purpose of the cache in the first place.